# Turning layout items invisible in Android layout

Tags: android

I am trying to turn some items visibility off when submitting a high score.

I have the following code but it does not appear to work.  Any suggestions?

mSignText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sign);

submitBtn = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);

mSignText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

submitBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1):

For visibility, you must use setVisibility as you have done:

- View.VISIBLE
- View.INVISIBLE
- View.GONE

GONE set the view as invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility

Comment: I tried both GONE and INVISIBLE and neither one seem to work.

Comment: You must have another problem. I use these functions without problem. Are you sure you have unique ids for each row ? Use this code not in the list but with one unique EditText or ImageView in your Layout.

Comment: I also wrapped the two items with the unique LinearLayout and tried that to no avail.